# Where can I find Overdrive Protocols?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Overdrive Protocols let you transfer Blades between Drivers, but they seem to be extremely limited. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to obtain Overdrive Protocols:

#### In Chests

You can find 3 Overdrive Protocols in chests:

- The chest in Torigoth, near the Driver Recruiters
- The chest in Garfont Village, behind the tents
- The barrel in Mor Ardain near the hot springs

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7j2696/xb2_overdrive_protocol_farming/)

#### Completing Driver Affinity

You can get a total of 5 Overdrive Protocols by completing each Driver's affinity web.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7i14lb/info_completing_a_drivers_affinity_chart_awards/)

#### Releasing Blades

You can release a **completed** 4 star Blade to get an Overdrive Protocol, which means they are farmable. You can (probably) only get a 4 star Blade from a Legendary Core. At least there's some consolation for "wasting" a Legendary Core.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7j2696/xb2_overdrive_protocol_farming/)

#### Buying Them For Bonus EXP

As of patch 1.3.0, you can find a [Traveling Bard in Tantal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/329683/56730) that will sell you an Overdrive Protocol for 1m bonus EXP.

#### Expansion Pass Gifts

You can get 10 Overdrive Protocols by purchasing the [Expansion Pass](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/xenoblade-chronicles-2-expansion-pass-70070000000644-switch/). They are split between 4 item sets: Driver Essentials Set (3), Driver Essentials Set 2 (1), Driver Essentials Set 3 (3), and Final Item Distribution List (3).