# Which common blades should I hold on to?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

While bonding with core crystals, I hit the limit for how many blades I can have at once. I need to start releasing Common Blades to make room, but I’m not sure what Blades I should release.

Are there any common blades I should hold on to? Which types of blades are ok to get rid of?

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can get rid of whatever you want. However, here are the guidelines I follow for if I should release a blade:

- Do I have enough of this field skill to pass a check if they randomly come up? If so, release it. My general thought here is that if I have approximately 10 that I can muster across all of my party members, that's good enough.
- Does it only have one field skill? If so, release it. I don't like single-use blades - more field skills means more utility in merc missions.
- Is it a 4 star common? Max it, then release it (for an [overdrive protocol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322832/56730)).

I can safely say that at max merc level, I probably have a hundred blade slots free per driver.

Answer (score 0):

Without repeating things off of Seiyria's excellent answer, here are two more considerations:

- High strength (30 then 35+) was the most difficult merc mission requirement for me.
- Merc level 2 is fairly easy to achieve and very early in the game.  I personally never hit the cap after that, although I had an endless stockpile of common cores I never used.

Comment: High strength is a byproduct of sending them on more merc missions, so having a maxxed out field skill or two will also imply high(er) strength.

Answer (score 0):

From my gaming experience, The only fields skills that I frequently not have enough are elemental skills.
This is because unique Blades rarely have elemental nodes.

So I basically only keep blades with (potential) level3 elemental nodes.
The only exception to this rule was if the blade have two or more other level 3 fields.

Comment: Part of this is not true. There are more blades with elemental bonuses than those without.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already excellent answers;

I tend to keep common blades who have the field skills that the uniques don't get; things like Production Mastery, Industry Mastery, Transport Mastery as popping a few of those on a relevant merc mission can really decrease the time needed to complete.