# What do each of the traveling bards do?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Traveling bards, in exchange for bonus experience, trade you items. They seem to be on every Titan. I think each one trades a different item. What can you get and at what prices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found on the [wiki](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Traveling_Bard):

- Argentum (Lemour Inn) - Accessory Expander Kit (+1 permanent accessory per driver) - costs 200k exp
- Gormott (Abbles Fountain) - 20000 Ether Crystals for 200k exp
- Uraya (Fonsa Myma Gate) - 1 Legendary Core Crystal for 200k exp
- Mor Ardain (Jakolos Inn) - 1 Ultimate Weaponry (+5k WP for a driver) - costs 400k exp
- Tantal (Theosir Main Gate) - 1 Overdrive Protocol - costs 1m exp
- Spirit Crucible Elpys (Upper Level - Spirit Crucible Entrance) - Elemental Core: Light - costs 1m exp
- Cliffs of Morytha (Upper Level - Cliffs of Morytha Inlet) - Master Ether Mod - costs 500k exp
- Cliffs of Morytha (Jubilee Gate) - Master Luck Mod - costs 500k exp
- Land of Morytha (Streets - View of a Lost Time) - Master Muscle Mod - costs 500k exp
- Land of Morytha (World Tree - Megaflote Base) - Master Strike Mod - costs 500k exp
- World Tree (Mid Level - Skywalk) - Master Evasion Mod - costs 500k exp
- World Tree (Lower Level - Lv. 2 Mizar: Lower Deck) - Master Tank Mod - costs 500k exp